# Python how to generate qrcode

Tags: python, django, qr-code

I'd like to generate a qr-code which will contain all informations concerning a user with django.

can you help me please....even with a link or a code...or with a github project ;)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) library. It should be able to do everything you need.

Here's a code snippet to get started:

```
import qrcode

qr_image = qrcode.make('cullzie')
qr_image.save('user_data_qr.png')
```